# Do i place .Includes( ) method before or after .find( )?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Where do i put .include() method for a rails model, before or after find?

```
User.find(1).includes(:books)
```

or

```
User.includes(:books).find(1)
```

Comment: [ActiveRecord docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) example places `.includes()` before `.find()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can *typically* swap the order on ActiveRecord association calls, but you can't do it in this case. find() returns the object itself, not a chainable scope.

If you were using a where clause, then the placement of the calls would not matter. You just need to ensure that you've added all the joins you need before the sql is actually executed.